# Can I pass credentials through command line securely?

Tags: windows, command-line, security, php, .net-framework

Before you think I should post it on an other forum - this is Windows OS related question, not programming.

I'm creating intranet website which needs user to authorize through Kerberos. After days of research I think that using PHP for this is not really best-way-to-do-it and I need to find other solution. So I got this idea, which works really good: I can use my knowledge in C# to use .NET Framework to do work for me. So I wrote (for now) little application, which uses Kerberos to check user credentials. I run application from PHP to check its return code something like:

> **myapplication.exe** user_name password1!
>
> (in near future it will get more information through command line)

It returns code based on authorization check, so my PHP application knows if it was success or not. Kerberos authorization is encrypted (that was super-easy with .NET), so I have "two birds with one stone". Of course, whole process is more complicated so I don't need to use it every single time, when user logins, but that's not the point here.

I'm asking questions, because I may learn something useful and I want to be sure:

Is this approach really secure?
Does anybody can get password which I'm passing to command line?
Can it be logged somewhere? And if yes - can I prevent this?
If this is not secure - can I pass credentials more safely?

It's really just one question "Is this secure?" but I want to give you some idea what I'm asking for. I don't want to go too far with this, unless I'm sure it's good idea. Also, everything is working perfectly so far.

I'm using Apache server on Windows Server with MySQL database (probably will change to MSSQL Express).

**[EDIT]**
I should point out that I'm using [exec()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) command in PHP. I'm asking if you can somehow get communication between Apache service starting/running **myapplication.exe**, because password is passed one-time-only there as plain text.

Comment: For intranet authentication, you probably want to either [talk to Kerberos directly](http://stackoverflow.com/q/389175/120999) or make use of a protocol like SAML or OAuth to handle authentication through your domain (the diagram on [Amazon's SAML docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_providers_enable-console-saml.html) might be useful).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this approach is insecure. On Windows, command line arguments are protected by user rights (technically it’s about access to the process object), but that’s not enough. A bug could exist in your web application that allows arbitrary code/command execution.

Instead, use stdin to “enter” the password. Of course, this requires that the application you’re calling knows to expect the password this way.

Also, you need to be very careful about passing user-provided command line arguments or I’ll just enter `; rm -rf /` as the username. ;)

---

By the way: This method will have significant performance implications unless you aggressively cache return values.

Comment: I'm using [exec()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) function in PHP. You can use safe mode as pointed in "Notes" section. Also, I'm not keeping user credentials, only pass them directly to "myapp.exe", it check if you can authorize in domain (encrypted by Kerberos protocol) and only returns code (0 for succeed and other for failures). Also, as I said, there's more logic behind this. It will not only pass arguments, because first you need to check if user exists in database. It is also not "free for all" application, because users are created by administrators.

Comment: I made small edit thanks to your answer. I hope it's more clear now. :)

Comment: Safe mode is long gone. It’s also not about “keeping” credentials. If they appear on the command line of a process, they have left your application’s control. That’s the most important point.

Comment: Good point about safe mode. But still a point of my question is: is there a way to interrupt this communication and gain access to a password? I can protect myself from running commands/script through username.

Comment: It’s not communication. It’s a property of the process object, which is managed by the operating system. Anyone with the appropriate permission can view the command line as long as the process is active. Passwords on the command line is a big no-no. Period.

Comment: So how should it be passed then? How can I view command line parameters of that process? Can I prevent it somehow? Your answers are not quite complete for me and are basically something like: "You shouldn't, because I think so." ;) No offense included, I'm only trying to gain some knowledge here, so I can improve security of whole application.

Comment: Standard Input, like I wrote in my answer. You can view command line parameters using your favorite task manager like Task Manager or Process Explorer. [The process command line should be considered public information.](https://www.google.com/search?q=security+implications+password+command+line)

Comment: I finally achieved this using Process Explorer and modifying application to stop while working. Thank you. Can you think of any other way to provide them to an external application?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45957/discussion-between-daniel-b-and-hagier).